# trigger translation to derby

Tags: sql, plsql, derby

I have the following pl sql trigger that i want to translate into derby.

source:

```
create or replace TRIGGER MyTrigger
BEFORE INSERT
ON myColumn
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  if(:new.id is null) then
  SELECT mySequence.nextval
  INTO :new.id
  FROM dual;
  end if;
END;
```

I altered the statement to work in derby into the following:

```
create TRIGGER myTrigger
no cascade BEFORE INSERT
ON myColumn
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
when(new.id is null)
(
  SELECT mySequence.nextval
  INTO :new.identnr
  FROM dual

)
end;
```

But i get an error, namely

> Error code 30000, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "insert"
>   at line 8, column 3.

So my question is basically: What is the equivalent of `select .. into` in derby?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `SELECT mySequence.nextval` is also incorrect: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/rrefsqljnextvaluefor.html#rrefsqljnextvaluefor

Comment: I guess i just didnt come this far. Thanks.

Comment: But why aren't you simply using a generated column and get rid of the trigger completely? http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/rrefsqlj37836.html

Comment: That is awesome, i didnt realize this exists in derby.